# Equality part of Holder's inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Given $ab=\dfrac{a^p}{p}+\dfrac{b^q}{q}$, where $p\ge 1$ and $\dfrac1p+\dfrac1q=1$, how does one show that $a^p=b^q$?

Answer (score 3):

Using weighted A.M.-G.M.([A.M.-G.M.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality)) we have,

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{p}(a^{p})+\frac{1}{q}(b^q)\ge (\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q})((a^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}(b^q)^{\frac{1}{q}})^{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}}}=ab$

We know that equality in case of A.M.-G.M. inequality holds iff the terms are equal.So $\displaystyle \frac{1}{p}(a^{p})+\frac{1}{q}(b^q)=ab$ would imply $a^p=b^q$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: check [Young's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality).